# how to use this C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

```
Program program1 = listProgram.Find(prg => prg.name.Contains("a"));
```

I want to display all the values of `Find(prg => prg.name.Contains("a")` so how can i display this I am trying using array and list.

Comment: Try *Linq*: `Program[] program1 = listProgram.Where(prg => prg.name.Contains("a")).ToArray();`

Answer (score 8):

`List<T>.Find` will simply return the very first `Program` in the list that fits your condition. What you want instead is a [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)-statement which returns *all* instances that satisfy the condition.

```
var programs = listProgram.Where(prg => prg.name.Contains("a"));
```

Now you may iterate those programs using a `foreach` for example or also convert the result to an array and access every instance via its index in that array.